# /bin/sh: /packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, ios-simulator

I run my Flutter project from Xcode, an error resulted so I took a look at an other post in stackoverflow and I read that "Now in order to find `xcode_backend.sh` the FLUTTER_ROOT variable needs to be defined. It is defined in a file called `Flutter/Generated.xcconfig`" and I have this file, then "The build configuration files `Debug.xcconfig` and `Release.xcconfig` (in the same Flutter folder) include `Generated.xcconfig`. Now the only thing left is to ensure that for each of the project configurations these build configuration files are properly set " but I don't have these files, my flutter folder only has `Generated.xcconfig`.
So I opened the `Runner.xcodeproj` and I saw that on the left column, in flutter folder, I have 3 red files which are :

`AppFrameworkInfo.plist`
`Release.xcconfig`
`Debug.xcconfig`.

I also noticed that in `Flutter.framework/Info.plist` under the voice `<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>` it was `<string>8.0</string>` so I changed it to `9.0` but after the run it was `8.0` again!
Do I have to create those file?

Answer (score -1):

Also change your version from 8.0 to 9.0 in `AppFrameWorkInfo.plist` and run `pod install` in terminal and run again, if it doesn't work then also try restarting your mac.

also try to change the deployment target in [General](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbjYu.jpg)

Comment: I did it but nothing changed, each time I change it it comes back to 8.0

Comment: pls check this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbjYu.jpg have you also change it, from here